# getting the absolute difference between two lists

Tags: python, list

I need to get the absolute difference between two lists, for example

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = a - b
difference = abs(a-b)
```

however, when I attempt to run the code I get an error that says:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

the return value needs to be a list, in this case, the difference is the return value

and by the absolute difference, I mean that the values within a list should positive

Comment: And what would be the absolute difference of two lists? The element-wise absolute difference?

Comment: `c = sum(a) - sum(b)` ?

Comment: What do you expect `c` to be?

Comment: As per the [help], please [search](//stackoverflow.com/help/searching) before asking. See also "[ask]".

Comment: Likely a duplicate of "[Subtracting 2 lists in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/534855/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

It is not completly clear how you define "absolute difference"

Could be this:

```
c = [abs(ai-bi) for ai ,bi in zip(a,b) ]
```

Or this:

```
c = sum([abs(ai-bi) for ai ,bi in zip(a,b) ])
```

or this:

```
c = abs(sum(a)-sum(b))
```

or this if is a vector like difference

```
from math import sqrt
c = sqrt(sum([(ai-bi)**2 for ai ,bi in zip(a,b) ]))
```